# AngularJS: radio checkbox model doesn't change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <input ng-change="change()" ng-repeat="item in array" ng-model="selected" name="group" value="{{item.interval}}" type="radio">{{item.desc}}</input>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.array = [ {
            interval: "1"
        }, {
            interval: "3"
        }, {
            interval: "24"
        }];

        $scope.selected = 1

        $scope.change = function () {
            console.log($scope.selected);
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I click different radio checkbox, the `$scope.selected` value doesn't change at all, still `1`.

But when I change the `$scope.selected` point to an object:

```
    $scope.selected = {
        value: 1
    };
```

and bind the input tag's model to the value property: `ng-model="selected.value"`. It work again.

Why? Why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Scope Issue**

---

It's because `ng-repeat` creates it's own scope. So `selected` is now a new property of ng-repeat's scope. If you absolutely needed to you could do this:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController"> //parent scope
   //ng-repeat create it's own scope here, so you must reference the $parent to get the selected value.
    <input ng-change="change()" ng-repeat="item in array" ng-model="$parent.selected" name="group" value="{{item.interval}}" type="radio">{{item.desc}}</input> // 
</div>
```

Rather than using `$parent` it would be better to use `object.property` as you have discovered.

### **Alternative**

---

Also, another way of doing it would be to add an update method to your controller. Because of **Scope Inheritance** you could access the parent method in your ng-repeat and update the parent scopes `selected` property:

```
//Add to your controller
$scope.updateSelected= function (selected) {
   $scope.selected = selected;
}

//new HTML
<div ng-controller="TestController">
        <input ng-change="updateSelected(selected)" ng-repeat="item in array" ng-model="selected" name="group" value="{{item.interval}}" type="radio">{{item.desc}}</input> // 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code for each radio button created `separate scope` so no affect when select another **radio button**. so you should use a `parent object` for each **radio button** and value set to this `parent object property` then will affect for every change.

like:
in your controller :

```
$scope.selectedInterval= {value: 1};
```

and in html:

```
<input  ng-repeat="item in array" ng-model="selectedInterval.value" name="group" value="{{item.interval}}" type="radio">{{item.desc}}</input>
```

here `selectedInterval` is parent object and `value` is property of `selectedInterval`. That's why no need to call `change` function.